# JQuery running only on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I have a question. So my goal is to create a dynamic form and I am using: 
http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/9jPcP/5/
as a basis for my form. You click on the check box and radio buttons appear. I understand the code - but my issue is, or what I believe it is, is that the hosting service I use for my site runs JRE 1.6.

The root issue is when I host on my PC and open my page in IE (yes I know - IE is the worst but I do not have a choice) the query works fine - I select the box the radio buttons appear instantaneously - I deselect and they disappear. BUT. When I run it on my host server the radio buttons only appear once I click off the checkbox. - specifically check the box and click some where else on the screen then the radio buttons appear.

I have tried:

```
    $(document).ready(function ds() {

            var displayVariableExhOptions = "";
            var displayText = "";
            if (document.input.sequenceOP14.checked) {
                displayText += "Checkbox 1 is checked";
                displayVariableExhOptions += "<input type='radio' name='exhOptions' id='sequenceOP15' onChange='displaySequence()' >"
                        + "Radio Box 1<br/>"
                        + "<input type='radio' name='exhOptions' id='sequenceOP16' onChange='displaySequence()' >"
                        + "Radio Box 2<br/>"
            }
            document.getElementById("variableSpdExhOptions").innerHTML = displayVariableExhOptions;
            document.getElementById("displayText").innerHTML = displayText;
        });
```

But then it stops working altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated: If you are using jQuery, instead of `document.getElementById("...")` use `$(#...")`. Also, use `.html("...")` instead of `.innerHTML = "..."`.

Comment: this comment actually just answered my next dilemma, thank you this was helpful

Comment: wouldn't it be $('#...') though? Although I can't seem to get it to work this way for some reason

Comment: Oh, yes it is. I must have missed the `"` key -- my apologies! It should be `$("#...")` for an ID. Use CSS selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using onclick instead of onchange:

```
onclick='displaySequence()'
```

IE only fires the onChange event when your checkbox loses focus (onblur) which would explain the behavior. It's not clear to me why it would be working when you are hosting on your PC but give it a try and see.